# Deactivate VLC's audio autogain / loudness maximizer /compressor with KDE

Tags: sound, kubuntu, vlc

Using VLC 3.0.16 on my Kubuntu 22.04 LTS I regularly notice artifacts from a badly configured audio compressor (pumping) and I wonder why VLC does this. Using Elisa, everything sounds as expected. But I dislike Elisa's unwillingness to let me use a file/dir selection dialog to select files and folders to play.

I am aware of VLC's "Effects and Filters" and especially the compressor. All effects are switched off.

How can I find out which process is responsible for the unwanted behaviour? How can I find out which sound pipeline both VLC and Elisa are using? The culprit must be there, I guess.